# MS Access Between dates query is not working

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, between

I'm an Access DB beginner. I have a database with a SearchForm where the user can enter search criteria, click the Search button and populate the subform with the filtered results.

The query has simple query based on what the user enters in fields in the search form

`Like "*" & [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtMicrochip] & "*"` which work well, but my date filter does not produce any results:
`Between [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivFrom] And [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivTo]`

The table fields that the date search is based on are Data Type:Date/Time , Format: Short Date
The Search Form fields are Format Short Date
The subform fields are also Short Date

SearchButton is a requery macro

And when I have the this query criteria in the query, none of the search functions work.
Any suggestions where I could look to solve the issue? Any help is appreciated.

Here is my SQL code for the search query,

```
FROM IndividualsT INNER JOIN SamplesT ON IndividualsT.AnimalID = SamplesT.AnimalID
WHERE (((IndividualsT.SpeciesName) Like "*" & [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtSpeciesName] & "*") AND 
((IndividualsT.Microchip) Like "*" & [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtMicrochip] & "*") AND 
((IndividualsT.Name) Like "*" & [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtName] & "*") AND
 ((SamplesT.Location) Like "*" & [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtLocation] & "*") AND
 ((SamplesT.SampleReceived) Between [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivFrom] And [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivTo]));
```

SamplesT

| SampleID | AnimalID | SampleReceived | Location | CollectionDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 18/08/2021 | Tassie | 10/08/2021 |
| 7 | 1 | 15/09/2021 | Berlin | 25/09/2021 |
| 13 | 12 | 25/09/2021 | Sydney | 4/09/2021 |
| 14 | 12 | 24/09/2021 | New York | 1/09/2021 |

IndividualsT

| AnimalID | SpeciesName | Microchip | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Parrot | 1234 | Hugo |
| 12 | Koala | 853 | Sherlock |

[image: SamplesTable_DesignView]

Comment: I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form or report. However, I tested and cannot replicate issue with dynamic query. Edit question to show sample data as text table.

Comment: I've entered some sample data. The data comes from two tables, tables are connected via the AnimalID field

Comment: *none of the search functions work* ... what does this mean? Please specify what actually happens. Zero results occur on the button click? Try debugging by taking out each `WHERE` condition to see which is the problematic one.

Comment: Have you built lookup fields in tables? You are showing dates as international structure. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: @Parfait when I don't include the between date criteria the other search functions work. however, when I add my Between Date search criteria, no results are returned for any of search boxes. The BetweenDate criteria are the problem, I just don't know why.

Comment: @KG12, does query work if all search boxes are filled in with values (i.e., none are empty). I have a working theory. Use wide enough date range to test. I assume those date textboxes are formatted as dates (not text) and align to your CPU region of dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: @June7 I'm in Australia :-)

Comment: @Parfait Ha, It works now if there's values in all of the date boxes, I can use the other txt boxes with and without values, and I can change the dates as required. I've set default values beyond the range that we would use, and it works. Which is ok, I guess. However, before this I had the setting that there are no records displayed when the form is opened, only after the search button is clicked, which obviously doesn't work now (all records are displayed upon opening the form).... Unless you've got a work around for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Likely, your issue is the `WHERE` logic when form fields are empty. When empty, `LIKE` expressions return as `**` which means anything, so no rows are filtered out. However, empty dates conflict with `BETWEEN` clause. Consider using `NZ` to return the column itself if form fields are empty:

```sql
(
  SamplesT.SampleReceived 
    BETWEEN NZ([Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivFrom], SamplesT.SampleReceived)
        AND NZ([Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivTo], SamplesT.SampleReceived)
);
```

Comment: This works, however I had the setting that there are no records are displayed in the subform when I open the search form, only after the search button is clicked, which doesn't work anymore. I'd prefer no to load all 20000 records every time someone opens the search form.

Answer (score 0):

Always specify the *data type* of the parameters:

```sql
Parameters
    [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtSpeciesName] Text ( 255 ),
    [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtMicrochip] Text ( 255 ),
    [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtName] Text ( 255 ),
    [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![txtLocation] Text ( 255 ),
    [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivFrom] DateTime,
    [Forms]![SampleSearchF]![DateReceivTo] DateTime;
Select *
From YourTable
Where ...
```

Comment: That worked for the date fields, Thanks! Bur now the other fields don't work anymore? They are unbound text boxes, I've added no additional formatting. Any ideas?

Comment: _the other fields don't work anymore_ ... that can't be true. Then something else is going on. Create a new simple query to verify, then expand this step by step.